# Separating Vue canvas component from JS object

Tags: javascript, canvas, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have pure JS object which is wrapper for canvas rendering library (PIXI).
For this question let's call it `Engine` and it looks something like this:

```
class Engine{
    constructor(options) {
        this.renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(options.width, options.height);
        // [...]

        // Add the canvas to the HTML document
        // * renderer.view is canvas element
        // * options.element is some <div> for example
        this.options.element.appendChild(this.renderer.view);
    }

    startRendering(){
        // This method uses this.renderer
        // [...]
    }

    stopRendering(){
        // This method uses this.renderer
        // [...]
    }

    // some other methods etc...
}
```

For now as you can see when Engine is created, it create pixi `renderer` and then appending `renderer.view` (canvas) to HTML tree.

I wanted to create **Canvas component** or **Engine component** to make it work in Vue but I do not know how should I divide or separate Engine object from component view.

The whole thing is that I want `Engine` object to be available in general by Vuex or other main "Controller" because I need access to methods like `start()` or `stop()` but at the same time I need to provide possibility to append canvas to component.

**How this should be done in Vue?** Should I create Engine component and create Engine + append canvas to `$el` and make it available by `$ref` or I should create somewhere global Engine object and pass renderer.view somehow to my canvas component to append it?
I want to note that I do not want Engine to be watched by Vue if I 'pin' it to component.